# Conversion of YAML Data to Data Frame using yamltodb

Tags: python, pandas, yaml

I am Trying to convert the YAML Data to Data frame through pandas with yamltodb package. but it is showing only the single row enclosed with header and only one data is showing. I tried to convert the Yaml file to JSON file and then tried normalize function. But it is not working out. Attached the screenshot for JSON function output. I need to categorize it under batman, bowler and runs etc.  [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUYFW.png)
[Output Image and their code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15v5J.png).

Comment: perhaps you should list the code not the image here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guessing, as I don’t know what your data actually looks like

```
import pandas as pd
import yaml

with open('fName.yaml', 'r') as f:
    df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(yaml.load(f))

df.head()
```