# How to extract specific parts from specific lines from a file?

Tags: python, pandas, list, file, yaml

I have a .yml file that I need to extract a specific part from specific lines.

This is what part of the file looks like (The file is 1200+ lines, but the structure is similar all throughout):

```
training:
trainings:
  - workout: Rec 016
    performed_at: 2020-06-25 09:04:16.295000076 Z
    star: false
    time: '00:04:00'
  - workout: Hanging knee raises endurance 10
    performed_at: 2020-06-25 08:59:11.871999979 Z
    star: true
    time: '00:00:28'
    repetitions: 10
  - workout: Str 700
    performed_at: 2020-06-25 08:57:51.039999961 Z
    star: true
    time: '00:15:30'
  - workout: Supermans technical 30
    performed_at: 2020-06-25 08:38:45.894000053 Z
    star: true
    time: '00:01:02'
  - workout: Toe touch crunches technical 20
    performed_at: 2020-06-25 08:37:05.439000129 Z
    star: true
    time: '00:00:54'
  - workout: Pre 028
    performed_at: 2020-06-25 08:35:33.243999958 Z
    star: false
    time: '00:06:30'
  - workout: Rec 001
    performed_at: 2020-06-22 22:51:38.947000026 Z
    star: false
    time: '00:05:01'
  - workout: Burpees standard 10
    performed_at: 2020-06-22 22:46:00.807000160 Z
    star: true
    time: '00:00:38'
```

Extra Info: With the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'text_data.yml')

with pd.option_context("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None):
    print(df)
```

This is what the file transforms into:

```
                                                    ---
0                                             training:
1                                            trainings:
2                                    - workout: Rec 016
3         performed_at: 2020-06-25 09:04:16.295000076 Z
4                                           star: false
5                                      time: '00:04:00'
6           - workout: Hanging knee raises endurance 10
7         performed_at: 2020-06-25 08:59:11.871999979 Z
8                                            star: true
9                                      time: '00:00:28'
10                                      repetitions: 10
11                                   - workout: Str 700
12        performed_at: 2020-06-25 08:57:51.039999961 Z
13                                           star: true
14                                     time: '00:15:30'
15                    - workout: Supermans technical 30
16        performed_at: 2020-06-25 08:38:45.894000053 Z
17                                           star: true
18                                     time: '00:01:02'
19           - workout: Toe touch crunches technical 20
20        performed_at: 2020-06-25 08:37:05.439000129 Z
21                                           star: true
22                                     time: '00:00:54'
23                                   - workout: Pre 028
24        performed_at: 2020-06-25 08:35:33.243999958 Z
25                                          star: false
26                                     time: '00:06:30'
27                                   - workout: Rec 001
28        performed_at: 2020-06-22 22:51:38.947000026 Z
29                                          star: false
30                                     time: '00:05:01'
```

What I am trying to do is extract the dates (Only the dates, nothing else) that are in the lines that start with "performed_at:" and put them into a list/DataFrame.

How would I go about doing this in the most efficient way possible through Pandas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to denormalize YAML for Pandas Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54259207/how-to-denormalize-yaml-for-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @dm2 My file is a YML not a YAML. I tried to incorporate their code to use my file but it did not work.

Comment: YML file is a YAML file. However, I see it's not mentioned in the answer I've linked, but the answer uses an external pyyaml library (yaml.load(f) is the part from this library). Can you describe how exactly it wasn't working?

Comment: @dm2 Oh, I thought the pyyaml library was built-in with pandas. Let me download it and I will get back to you.

Comment: also check this answer as it is more filled out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53892729/13590089

Comment: Alright, I got it working, but the new format doesn't make sense anymore. The structure this file is in just doesn't work when transformed into a DataFrame. I think I'm going to have to work with the unmodified file. How would I go about it if I wanted to parse through each line? Thank you for all the help so far.

Comment: It seems to work for me. Do one last thing, try this for me: `with open('file.yml', 'r') as f:
    df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(yaml.load(f), 'trainings')` 
This gives me a dataframe with all the fields from which I can then select a performed_at column. This is directly taken from the answers in previously posted questions (thus I'm posting here and not in answer)

Comment: It gave me an error: "KeyError: trainings". I think my only way of doing this is with the file as is, then use regex to pinpoint the dates and extract them there. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: Very well might be. I hope somebody might have other suggestions. However, just in case, if the `'trainings'` portion of your data is indented in the .yml file, you would have to replace `'trainings'` (in `json_normalize` call) to a list of `'trainings'` and all the preceding headers, such as for example if the whole 'listings' portion was indented one extra step from 'training', you'd have to pass a `['training', 'trainings']` instead of just `'trainings'`.

Comment: @dm2 The ['training', 'trainings'] worked!

Comment: Thought it might :D Not sure if this should be written out as an answer or marked as duplicate question: most of this was from the answers linked before :)

Comment: I feel the question might be helpful to some others, although I could be wrong. I've kept the question up and have written an answer pointing to this thread for the answer. Thank you again for your help and patience.

Answer (score 0):

For the solution, please read the comments made under the question. Thanks to @dm2.